# SVG gradient or filter

Tags: svg, gradient, svg-filters

I'm trying to reproduce the effect in this screenshot:

[image]

I created it in HTML + CSS, but now want to do it in SVG + CSS.

The current HTML code looks like this:

```
<div class="key mag " style="left:614px;top:182px;width:68px;height:68px;">
    <div class="caphgh">I</div>
    <div class="caprgt"></div>
    <div class="keyopt">Inventory</div>
    <div class="keyshf"></div>
    <div class="keyctl"></div>
    <div class="keyalt"></div>
    <div class="keyagr"></div>
    <div class="keyxtr"></div>
</div>
```

The current stylesheet code looks something like this:

```
.mag
{
    background:#E4A0DB; /* CIE-L*ch ( 74, 40,330) */
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 50%, transparent 50%, transparent);
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 50%, transparent 50%, transparent);
    background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 50%, transparent 50%, transparent);
    background-size:72px 72px;
}
```

Also, I don't know beforehand what the base color is going to be. It could be magenta, red, or one of several other colors.

I'm not sure how to do this in SVG, and would appreciate some help. Thank you.

[edit]

I just experimented with creating a new mask for each rectangle in PHP using customized code. This is as opposed to keeping a single mask in `defs` and repeatedly using it.

This works in Chrome and IE if you give each mask a different ID. But this means I can't use the `mask:url(#Mask);` CSS property, and thus a "pure" CSS solution.

[edit]

Per Paul's suggestions, I have created a rectangle like this:

```
<svg fill="#ff0000">
    <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" rx="4" ry="4" width="50" height="50" fill="url(#grad_3)"/>
</svg>
```

I also have a linear gradient set in `defs`.

```
<linearGradient id="grad_3" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
    <stop id="fade-stop-1" offset="0.0" stop-opacity="1.0" />
    <stop id="fade-stop-2" offset="0.5" stop-opacity="1.0" />
    <stop id="fade-stop-3" offset="0.5" stop-opacity="1.0" />
    <stop id="fade-stop-4" offset="1.0" stop-opacity="1.0" />
</linearGradient>
```

And some CSS:

```
#fade-stop-1 {stop-color: white;}
#fade-stop-2 {stop-color: white;}
#fade-stop-3 {stop-color: currentColor;}
#fade-stop-4 {stop-color: currentColor;}
```

However, the result is a rectangle that is half white and half black instead of half white and half red. What is my mistake?

[edit]

I think my mistake was that the SVG tag should use `color="#ff0000"` instead of `fill="#ff0000"`. I'm not sure yet, as I haven't tested it.

Comment: Last I checked, CSS gradients are not supported on SVG elements.  You would need to use normal SVG `<linearGradient>` and `<radialGradient>` elements.

Comment: Is there a way to pass a color off as a parameter to one of these gradients? Otherwise I have to create one gradient for every color. It's meant for Wikipedia, so I am not allowed to use JavaScript.

Comment: I *can* use PHP to generate whatever is needed, however.

Comment: You might be able to use fill:currentColor

Comment: I don't understand. Where would I use it? In the mask, or in the rectangle? Could you provide some code?

Comment: You would use it as the value of `stop-color` in your `<stop>` element. Eg. `<stop offset="0%" stop-color="currentColor">`.  `currentColor` is a special color keyword that means the current value of CSS `color`.

Comment: Note also that you can style `stop-color` and `stop-opacity` with CSS. So you can use CSS classes to modify gradient colours if you need to.  Maybe you can use this to save time, but in general you are correct. You usually have to have one gradient element per gradient colour set.

Comment: CSS `color` only applies to HTML, right? I think `currentColor` is only for passing a color from HTML to SVG. I don't see how it works in pure SVG.

Comment: CSS color applies to HTML **and** currentColor. You can specify a color on an element (which SVG will normally ignore) and then use it via currentColor

Comment: Okay, I will keep that in mind.